# Automate sale order to invoice creation in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Is there an easy way to automate the sale order process ? 
I have customer whose salesman will create Sale orders for every sim he creates.
Once Sale order is closed both DC and Invoice should be created and validated automatically, there is no need for stock picking/packing concepts.
Could someone have any idea on doing it without affecting the default flow ?
Or should I call every function related to that process in my module ?

I tried calling the functions in stock picking and then tried validating DC. I got the odoo Warning as

```
'You have a difference between quantity on the operation and the quantities specified for the lots'
```

Could you please suggest me which particular function picks the product from stock in stock.picking ?

Comment: pass create method with values for sale order and call invice create button via python

Comment: I tried this, but the product count from the stock remained the same.

Comment: you have to automate until GRN which mean have create delivery against that sale order with procurement group

Comment: did you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi  Nirmalraj Rethinasabapathi,
Yes, I think I have done it for my project.
I can map What I have done to achieve that:

1. Added two boolean fields in Warehouse form.
2. One for "Auto Validate Invoice" and another one is for "Automation In Delivery"
3. Override sales confirmation button action and bypass all the function you want.

It is working perfectly for me.